# JAXB - Element is not turned to a class

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jaxb

I'm doing a conversion from maven to gradle,
the project I'm converting is currently using the maven plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schema</schemaDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

the following element generates a SomeClass.class file in the target dir:

```
<xs:element name="SomeClass" type="SomeClassType">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <meta:content-type>
                    application/xml;application/json;class=com.example
                </meta:content-type>
            </xs:appinfo>
            <xs:documentation source="since">5.7</xs:documentation>
            <xs:documentation xml:lang="en">
                ...
            </xs:documentation>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:element>
```

For gradle I went for this plugin: https://github.com/jacobono/gradle-jaxb-plugin
which generates source files instead of .class files, which is fine, but it does not generate a class for that specific element

```
jaxb {
    xsdDir = "${projectDir.path - rootDir.path}/src/main/resources/schema"
    episodesDir = "${buildDir.path - rootDir.path}/schema/episodes"
    xjc {
        destinationDir = jaxbDstDir
        producesDir = jaxbDstDir
    }
}
```

with:

```
  jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.2.11'
  jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-xjc:2.2.11'
  jaxb 'com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.2.11'
```

the dependencies are the same as the maven plugin is using,
other classes are generated okay

Any ideas why?

Comment: This looks like a version problem, make sure Gradle *really* uses 2.2.11 for compilation.

Comment: do you have any particular class in mind? grade does seem to load classes out of the mentioned jars

Comment: No, not really. Do you maybe have an `*.xjb` customization in the first (Maven) case? Because XJC normally does not produce classes for global elements unless told to.

Comment: yes I do: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jaxb:bindings jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" version="2.1"
  xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
  xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">
  <jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel">
    <xjc:simple/>
  </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>`

Comment: So maybe `*.xjb` is not considered by the Gradle plugin?

Comment: I added a declaration for bindings, now I get import errors `Cannot resolve the name '…' to a(n) 'type definition' component` although there are imports in place pointing to the right file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74358/discussion-between-sagioto-and-lexicore).